# 80s Mecha anime/cartoon about a giant spaceship that could transform into a humanoid robot form

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, mecha, animated-series

Need help finding the title of anime or cartoon movie or series, from the late 80s or early 90s.

All I remember is that it was about a giant spaceship that could transform into a humanoid robot form.

One of the episodes or part of the movie was about a baby boy who aged over night into an adult. Even after ageing or growing up he behaved like a newborn.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this that you can [edit] in? Any detail can help us identify this for you.

Comment: Giant spaceship robot --> The SDF 1 comes to mind, but I don't remember Macross (or the Robotech series patchwork) featuring any episode like the one you describe.

Comment: Slightly reminiscent of [Megas XLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megas_XLR), but the date is wrong and I don't remember the episode described.

Comment: After googling images of Robotech I think it could be it. The spaceship looks like the one from my memories. Couldn't find the plot with the baby in the series summaries. I'll try watching it, maybe that refreshes my mind.

Comment: @Demiurg As you appear to be the OP you should really consider [registering your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161) and then requesting an [account merge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) as this information probably belongs in a comment to your question until you find out if this truly is what you were looking for.

Comment: Doesn't involve a robot ship, but the boy-aged-to-adult plot is in the pilot episode of Thundercats.

Answer (score 8):

This is a long shot but it's possible you're conflating two different animated series, which I recall often aired together around that time period in the US. (though you didn't say where you saw this) This was suggested in comments by [SPArchaeologist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/53529/sparchaeologist) and [MarbleMunkey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/109951/marblemunkey).

**Robotech**

> Within the combined and edited story, Robotechnology refers to the scientific advances discovered in an alien starship that crashed on a South Pacific island. With this technology, Earth developed giant robotic machines or mecha (**many of which were capable of transforming into vehicles**) to fight three successive extraterrestrial invasions.

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia, Robotech (TV Series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotech_(TV_series))</sup>

Specifically the [SDF-1 Macross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDF-1_Macross) can transform between spaceship and giant robot form.

**Thundercats**

The first episode featured something like "*a baby boy who aged over night into an adult*".

> ...Lion-O is now a grown-up ThunderCat. His sleep-chamber was damaged and his body grew many years older while the others remained in suspended animation. He is now no longer a Thunderkitten ...despite still having the mind of a child and lacking the experiences that would make him a good leader.

<sup>Source: [Thundercats wiki, Exodus](http://thundercats.wikia.com/wiki/Exodus)</sup>

[An infant version of Lion-O](http://www.thundercatsfans.org/graphix/appear/babyliono.jpg) was also featured in the episode "Time Switch". (and also in [the 2011 remake of Thundercats](https://statici.behindthevoiceactors.com/behindthevoiceactors/_img/chars/lion-o-baby-thundercats-26.6.jpg))

**Both series originally aired in 1985.** In 1998 Thundercats and Robotech aired as part of the same lineup on Toonami (Cartoon Network). Here's a promo. **Even if you didn't see it on this channel, it's very possible you would have seen them together**.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Space Firebird aka Hi no tori 2772: Ai no cosmozone. See https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0079293/

There are some other related works anime, manga, games related to this title, most notably the 2004 tv series remake.

> The beginning of the movie shows the main character, Godo, growing from an embryo to a child in an incubator in a timelapse fashion as Op remembers. Also the humanoid robot and Godo's nurse, Olga can transform into a car and even into a spaceship

The imdb page contains many [screenshots](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0079293/mediaindex) from the movie, also there's this youtube trailer

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer by directly including some relevant pictures to make it easier for the person who asked the question to recognize this.

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of early anime that meet your criteria, but I have a sneaking suspicion the "mech" you speak of here was the Ramrod Unit. Does this look like the Mech in question?

[image]

And was *this* its vehicle form?

[image]

If so, then what you are thinking of is  *Saber Rider & the Star Sheriffs* a mid 80s, 1 season anime. However, you **could** also be thinking of either **Mobile Suit Gundam** or one of its later versions, or one of the various  **Voltron** incarnations.